How to fix my PC after an accidental reboot during upgrade to ubuntu 24.04?
I tried to upgrade my pc from ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 with "do-release-upgrade" and I accidental reboot during upgrade by "ctrl + alt + del".
Here's what I got when booted into Ubuntu.

If I use "ctrl + alt + f3", it gives me "login incorrect" (I was fine with that username before the upgrade.)

I go to the Recovery mode console, I can see all my data still there.

I run dpkg --configure -a, but I got this error message.

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libedataserverui4-1.0-0t64:amd64:
 libedataserverui4-1.0-0t64:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.66.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 libedataserverui4-1.0-0t64:amd64 depends on libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.1.1); however:
  Package libsoup-3.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libedataserverui4-1.0-0t64:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgweather-4-0t64:amd64:
 libgweather-4-0t64:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not installed.
 libgweather-4-0t64:amd64 depends on libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3); however:
  Package libsoup-3.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgweather-4-0t64:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcamel-1.2-64t64:amd64:
 libcamel-1.2-64t64:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.64.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libcamel-1.2-64t64:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cheese:
 cheese depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 cheese depends on libgtk-3-0t64 (>= 3.21.5); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package cheese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtext-iconv-perl:amd64:
 libtext-iconv-perl:amd64 depends on perl-base (>= 5.38.2-3); however:
  Version of perl-base on system is 5.34.0-3ubuntu1.3.
 libtext-iconv-perl:amd64 depends on perlapi-5.38.2; however:
  Package perlapi-5.38.2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libtext-iconv-perl:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins:amd64:
 speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins:amd64 depends on libasound2t64 (>= 1.0.18); however:
  Package libasound2t64 is not installed.
 speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.36); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packagekit-tools:
 packagekit-tools depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.54); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package packagekit-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xdg-desktop-portal-gtk:
 xdg-desktop-portal-gtk depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 xdg-desktop-portal-gtk depends on libgtk-3-0t64 (>= 3.21.5); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xdg-desktop-portal-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gtk3:
 libreoffice-gtk3 depends on libatk1.0-0t64 (>= 2.11.90); however:
  Package libatk1.0-0t64 is not installed.
 libreoffice-gtk3 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 libreoffice-gtk3 depends on libgtk-3-0t64 (>= 3.21.5); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gtk3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64:
 libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64 depends on perl-base (>= 5.38.2-3); however:
  Version of perl-base on system is 5.34.0-3ubuntu1.3.
 libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64 depends on perlapi-5.38.2; however:
  Package perlapi-5.38.2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-browsed:
 cups-browsed depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 cups-browsed depends on libldap2 (>= 2.6.2); however:
  Package libldap2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package cups-browsed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gtk-update-icon-cache:
 gtk-update-icon-cache depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.57.2); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gtk-update-icon-cache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxml-parser-perl:
 libxml-parser-perl depends on perlapi-5.38.2; however:
  Package perlapi-5.38.2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libxml-parser-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tracker:
 tracker depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package tracker (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udisks2:
 udisks2 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package udisks2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwhoopsie-preferences0:
 libwhoopsie-preferences0 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libwhoopsie-preferences0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdebuginfod1t64:amd64:
 libdebuginfod1t64:amd64 depends on libcurl3t64-gnutls (>= 7.28.0); however:
  Package libcurl3t64-gnutls is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libdebuginfod1t64:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of session-migration:
 session-migration depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.51.1); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package session-migration (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64:
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 depends on libatk1.0-0t64 (>= 1.32.0); however:
  Package libatk1.0-0t64 is not installed.
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 depends on libgtk-3-0t64 (>= 3.23.0); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0t64 is not installed.
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 depends on libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2); however:
  Package libpng16-16t64 is not installed.
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 depends on libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3); however:
  Package libsoup-3.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dbus:
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (>= 3.12~); however:
  Version of python3 on system is 3.10.6-1~22.04.
 python3-dbus depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.16.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgck-2-2:amd64:
 libgck-2-2:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgck-2-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shotwell:
 shotwell depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 shotwell depends on libgtk-3-0t64 (>= 3.21.5); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0t64 is not installed.
 shotwell depends on libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3); however:
  Package libsoup-3.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shotwell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcanberra0t64:amd64:
 libcanberra0t64:amd64 depends on libasound2t64 (>= 1.0.16); however:
  Package libasound2t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libcanberra0t64:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcanberra-gtk0:amd64:
 libcanberra-gtk0:amd64 depends on libcanberra0t64 (>= 0.12); however:
  Package libcanberra0t64:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libcanberra-gtk0:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.12.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libcanberra-gtk0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of system-config-printer-common:
 system-config-printer-common depends on python3-dbus; however:
  Package python3-dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package system-config-printer-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgeoclue-2-0:amd64:
 libgeoclue-2-0:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgeoclue-2-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-control-center:
 gnome-control-center depends on libadwaita-1-0 (>= 1.4~beta); however:
  Version of libadwaita-1-0:amd64 on system is 1.1.0-1ubuntu2.
 gnome-control-center depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 gnome-control-center depends on libgnome-desktop-4-2t64 (>= 3.33.4); however:
  Package libgnome-desktop-4-2t64 is not installed.
 gnome-control-center depends on libgnutls30t64 (>= 3.7.0); however:
  Package libgnutls30t64 is not installed.
 gnome-control-center depends on libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3); however:
  Package libsoup-3.0-0 is not installed.
 gnome-control-center depends on libwhoopsie-preferences0 (>= 0.9); however:
  Package libwhoopsie-preferences0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xdg-desktop-portal:
 xdg-desktop-portal depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 xdg-desktop-portal depends on libpipewire-0.3-0t64 (>= 0.3.1); however:
  Package libpipewire-0.3-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xdg-desktop-portal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs:amd64:
 gvfs:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libportal1:amd64:
 libportal1:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libportal1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libblockdev-mdraid3:amd64:
 libblockdev-mdraid3:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.42.2); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libblockdev-mdraid3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglibmm-2.68-1t64:amd64:
 libglibmm-2.68-1t64:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.77.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libglibmm-2.68-1t64:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpangoxft-1.0-0:amd64:
 libpangoxft-1.0-0:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libpangoxft-1.0-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcr-4-4:amd64:
 libgcr-4-4:amd64 depends on libgck-2-2 (= 4.2.0-5); however:
  Package libgck-2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgcr-4-4:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgcr-4-4:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libzvbi0t64:amd64:
 libzvbi0t64:amd64 depends on libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2); however:
  Package libpng16-16t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libzvbi0t64:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnma-gtk4-0:amd64:
 libnma-gtk4-0:amd64 depends on libgck-2-2 (>= 4.0.0); however:
  Package libgck-2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libnma-gtk4-0:amd64 depends on libgcr-4-4 (>= 3.8.0); however:
  Package libgcr-4-4:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libnma-gtk4-0:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.38.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libnma-gtk4-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of evolution-data-server:
 evolution-data-server depends on libcamel-1.2-64t64 (= 3.52.0-1build3); however:
  Package libcamel-1.2-64t64:amd64 is not configured yet.
 evolution-data-server depends on libcanberra0t64 (>= 0.2); however:
  Package libcanberra0t64:amd64 is not configured yet.
 evolution-data-server depends on libdb5.3t64; however:
  Package libdb5.3t64 is not installed.
 evolution-data-server depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.70.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 evolution-data-server depends on libgtk-3-0t64 (>= 3.10); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0t64 is not installed.
 evolution-data-server depends on libgweather-4-0t64 (>= 4.1); however:
  Package libgweather-4-0t64:amd64 is not configured yet.
 evolution-data-server depends on libldap2 (>= 2.6.2); however:
  Package libldap2 is not installed.
 evolution-data-server depends on libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.1.1); however:
  Package libsoup-3.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package evolution-data-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkf5notifications5:amd64:
 libkf5notifications5:amd64 depends on libcanberra0 (>= 0.2); however:
  Package libcanberra0 is not installed.
  Package libcanberra0t64:amd64 which provides libcanberra0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkf5notifications5:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-keyring:
 gnome-keyring depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.77.3); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-keyring (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmsgraph-0-1:amd64:
 libmsgraph-0-1:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 libmsgraph-0-1:amd64 depends on libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3); however:
  Package libsoup-3.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libmsgraph-0-1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcurl4t64:amd64:
 libcurl4t64:amd64 depends on libldap2 (>= 2.6.2); however:
  Package libldap2 is not installed.
 libcurl4t64:amd64 depends on libpsl5t64 (>= 0.16.0); however:
  Package libpsl5t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libcurl4t64:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libblockdev-crypto3:amd64:
 libblockdev-crypto3:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.42.2); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libblockdev-crypto3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libref-util-xs-perl:
 libref-util-xs-perl depends on perlapi-5.38.2; however:
  Package perlapi-5.38.2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libref-util-xs-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgdm1:
 libgdm1 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgdm1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of slirp4netns:
 slirp4netns depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.28.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package slirp4netns (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwireplumber-0.4-0:amd64:
 libwireplumber-0.4-0:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.62.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 libwireplumber-0.4-0:amd64 depends on libpipewire-0.3-0t64 (>= 0.3.68); however:
  Package libpipewire-0.3-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libwireplumber-0.4-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkitgtk-6.0-4:amd64:
 libwebkitgtk-6.0-4:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.79.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 libwebkitgtk-6.0-4:amd64 depends on libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2); however:
  Package libpng16-16t64 is not installed.
 libwebkitgtk-6.0-4:amd64 depends on libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3); however:
  Package libsoup-3.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libwebkitgtk-6.0-4:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-draw:
 libreoffice-draw depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.12.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 libreoffice-draw depends on libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2); however:
  Package libpng16-16t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-draw (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpoppler134:amd64:
 libpoppler134:amd64 depends on libcurl3t64-gnutls (>= 7.16.2); however:
  Package libcurl3t64-gnutls is not installed.
 libpoppler134:amd64 depends on libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2); however:
  Package libpng16-16t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libpoppler134:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-session-canberra:
 gnome-session-canberra depends on libcanberra0t64 (>= 0.2); however:
  Package libcanberra0t64:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gnome-session-canberra depends on libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.16.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0t64 is not installed.
 gnome-session-canberra depends on libgtk-3-0t64 (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0t64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-session-canberra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libedataserverui4-1.0-0t64:amd64
 libgweather-4-0t64:amd64
 libcamel-1.2-64t64:amd64
 cheese
 libtext-iconv-perl:amd64
 speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins:amd64
 packagekit-tools
 xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
 libreoffice-gtk3
 libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64
 cups-browsed
 gtk-update-icon-cache
 libxml-parser-perl
 tracker
 udisks2
 libwhoopsie-preferences0
 libdebuginfod1t64:amd64
 session-migration
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0:amd64
 python3-dbus
 libgck-2-2:amd64
 shotwell
 libcanberra0t64:amd64
 libcanberra-gtk0:amd64
 system-config-printer-common
 libgeoclue-2-0:amd64
 gnome-control-center
 xdg-desktop-portal
 gvfs:amd64
 libportal1:amd64
 libblockdev-mdraid3:amd64
 libglibmm-2.68-1t64:amd64
 libpangoxft-1.0-0:amd64
 libgcr-4-4:amd64
 libzvbi0t64:amd64
 libnma-gtk4-0:amd64
 evolution-data-server
 libkf5notifications5:amd64
 gnome-keyring
 libmsgraph-0-1:amd64
 libcurl4t64:amd64
 libblockdev-crypto3:amd64
 libref-util-xs-perl
 libgdm1
 slirp4netns
 libwireplumber-0.4-0:amd64
 libwebkitgtk-6.0-4:amd64
 libreoffice-draw
 libpoppler134:amd64
 gnome-session-canberra
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.

I tried with apt --fix-broken install, but I got this error message.

How to fix my Ubuntu 24.04? or Can I roll back to the old version? I want to login into my PC normally again, no matter if it's 24.04 or 22.04. I don't have any backup files.

Rolling back to your old system is done via restoration of backups, and we cannot know what backup strategy you put in place unless you tell us.  If you didn't make any (as you seem to indicate), a non-destructive re-install maybe in order, but you gave few specifics there, as there can be complications on that depending on what you were using & thus upgraded, as well as what package(s) you'd added to your unstated system.

This question is similar to: How to revert a do-release-upgrade?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

An answer I've written here on this site maybe worth considering, esp. if you're talking about a Desktop install and not Server install (and not using Server apps), but it's not currently possible using 24.04 ISOs using ubuntu-desktop-installer, or older releases using the same installer (with internet connected; which you'll need for the install to work!), but would be an option if 22.04 Desktop possibly. It's something I'd for sure consider (and have used it myself in the last 4 days)

@guiverc thank you so much, I'm reading you post right now. I'm using desktop, not server.

@guiverc hi, is is possible to create any usboot with ubuntu 24.04 and repair my system?

If a system was in the do-release-upgrade and doing the first download packages part, its super easy to correct issues, as only your sources need correcting...  If however packages started to install its complex, especially if you don't know where is was..  Ubuntu 24.04 ISOs using calamares are an option, but not ideal for Ubuntu Desktop; they don't have the force format issue that exists (currently) with ubuntu-desktop-installer (I talk about that here)

If you refer to the link in my last comment, the Ubuntu Desktop install will force format which will cause loss of data on your system partition, if you have a separate /home partition your actual data should be safe, but you won't have programs auto-reinstall etc. that I talk about in my initial repair install type scenario... The Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop ISO will use ubiquity which does not have the forced format issue I'm talking about here & last comment   The 3 ISOs using `calamares installer for 24.04 will cause your desktop to change; not ideal if you don't know how to revert

Yeah, all my data is still in /home but I in my browser, I have a lot of thing on it. and I dont want to lost it. :( I just want to repair my ubuntu, like I can login into it and using like before upgrade ( don't want to login socical account, gmail, bookmark...)
p/s: with my error pc now, I can still access into internet with recovery mode. Ping 8.8.8.8 is fine.

ah, I remember that after the system ask me about install snap thurderbird and it go to black screen. and I did reboot.

@guiverc I have just posted the log when I tried to fixed my system in the thread.

can you try sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb please

wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nettle/libnettle8t64_3.9.1-2.2build1_amd64.deb Install the deb with dpkg if possible; maybe this way apt is usable again. And backup your persanal data before!!!

Your output clearly shows that your system is in an inconsistent state. Sometimes that can be fixed. Sometimes it cannot.
Interrupting a release-upgrade is about the worst thing you could have done. Try to never do that.

Back up your data in case a reinstall is needed or you make another "accident" for yourself.

After your data is backed up, run sudo apt update. Fix any errors. Do not proceed until sudo apt update runs with no errors.

After your apt sources are fixed, run sudo apt dist-upgrade to attempt to complete the interrupted release-upgrade. Read carefully the output of any errors. You might need to --reinstall a package that was incompletely installed due to the interruption.

If you cannot eliminate all apt errors, or you make more "accidents" that further damage your system, then reinstall Ubuntu. Do not continue to use a broken system -- that's how you lose data.



Great answer but it may take days.

It may be simpler to use a live USB to back up the data and reinstall

@ArchismanPanigrahi agreed, that's steps #1 and #4. The OP asked specifically "how to fix", so reinstalling is the backup plan.
